# Dell Inspiron N5050 connected to the MI TV via hdmi display not synced

Tags: xubuntu, display, dell, hdmi

We have connected the Dell Inspiron N5050 via HDMI port to MI TV.
Diplay is showing in the MI TV, but only the start up screen and TV is not
in sync with the laptop.

[image]

The left side screen is the laptop screen and the right side screen is the TV screen.

If I use mirror displays
[image]

The laptop screen gets shrunk and TV screen is full.

[image]

Comment: Use windows button and P to cycle display states.

Comment: @kukulo if we use windows button and p there are four options available only mirror displays showing display in both laptop and TV. The size of the screen gets shrunk in Laptop.

Comment: Yes that is normal if you use the mirror display option. If you use extend display then you can adjust the resolution separately.